# In concrete5.7, how does one change an image in a content block?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

In 5.7, is it possible to place an image in a content block and then, thereafter, edit that image? Whenever I click on the image in Redactor, it just gives me link editing stuff, not the ability to change the image itself.

Comment: As it is in a content block, I'd say just delete it and add another one...

Comment: If you go to the file manager I believe there is a "Replace" function that is available for those files. This would be appropriate if you wanted to replace all instances of it, otherwise I'd agree with @pc-shooter and say just remove it and add your replacement in its place

Comment: Yeah, not really a solution, I think you'd agree, particularly when the functionality used to exist. Seems like for now it's just a no go. Oh wells.

Comment: How would you replace a word in a content block?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can from the Filemanager. If you go there and find the file you've entered through Redactor, you'll have the options to *edit* and *replace* the image.

[image: screenshot]